# faster/better way to split data frame

Tags: r

Hello i'm wondering if there is a better way to do this :

```r
# any test and or data frame those ones are just for the exemple
test <- sample(rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),times = 100000),10000)
dat <- data.frame(A = numeric(10000),B=character(10000),C=factor('expl'))

datYes <- dat[test,]
datNo <- dat[!test]
```

the idea is to split a data frame in to with a condtion if the condition is true data goes in data frame 1 an if it's false in a second

what i mean by a better way is a fester way, i'm currently using data.frame but i will change to data.table and my main idea is using the fastest way for data.table even if it's currently slower as i will switch soon

Comment: How will you be using this code (in production) that the current implementation is slow? What would you consider an acceptable faster solution?

Comment: It is not split but subset 2x, data.table should scale better. The way you use should be fast, try verbose argument. It make sense to go deeper only if you loop this subset many times. See https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**data.table** is definitely much faster and efficient than the standard `data.frame` class. You can use binary search to achieve what you have in mind.

Below I am using the `iris` dataset to show you how it works.

```r
library(data.table)

data("iris")
setDT(iris)

set.seed(1970)
iris[ , test := sample(rep( c(TRUE, FALSE), times = nrow(iris)), nrow(iris)) ]

setkey(iris, test)
iris_true = iris[ .(TRUE) ]
iris_false = iris[ .(FALSE) ]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can achieve the same thing through:

```r
iris_true = iris[ test == TRUE ]
iris_false = iris[ test == FALSE ]
```

Bear in mind the first method is way more efficient and faster.

If I may, I would suggest you to do the investment in learning **data.table** which is a great package with a very clear syntax.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want

```
list2env(setNames(split(dat,test),c("datNo","datYes")),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```